# Symfony 2 and Doctrine. Delete parent on table inheritance

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have the following structure:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"notice" = "UserNoticeNotification", "change_shift" = "ChangeShiftRequestNotification", "change_watch" = "ChangeWatchRequestNotification"})
 */
class Notification {

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * @ORM\Table(name="notification_user_notice")
 */
class UserNoticeNotification extends Notification {

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Intranet\WebBundle\Entity\Notice",cascade={"remove"})
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="notice_id", referencedColumnName="id",onDelete="CASCADE")
    **/
    protected $notice;
```

My problem is when I remove a notice referenced in a UserNoticeNotification the row in table "`notification_user_notice`" is removed but not the row in the parent table "`notification`".

I have trying with a `postRemove` listener but it is not called because of the delete is made at table level.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Have you generated the table setup SQL with the Doctrine schema tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved using a EventListener with a PreRemove action:

```
public function preRemove(LifecycleEventArgs $args) {
    $entity = $args->getEntity();
    $em = $args->getEntityManager();
    if (get_class($entity) == 'Intranet\WebBundle\Entity\Notice') {
        $notificationRepository = $em->getRepository('IntranetNotificationsBundle:UserNoticeNotification');
        $notifications = $notificationRepository->findByNotice($entity);
        foreach ($notifications as $notification) {
            $em->remove($notification);
        }
        $em->flush();
    }
}
```

and defining the entity like:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * @ORM\Table(name="notification_user_notice")
 */
class UserNoticeNotification extends Notification {

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Intranet\WebBundle\Entity\Notice")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="notice_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    **/
    protected $notice;
```